# restore() throws InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, php-7.3

This works fine:

```php
$post->comments()->withTrashed()->get()->each->delete();
```

Since it does indeed delete the 6 rows the `each` returns as a Collection.

However, this throws an exception:

```php
$post->comments()->withTrashed()->get()->each->restore();
```

I noticed it also restored 1 row (the first row) in the database (the Collection has 6 rows).

Context: I use such code in an Observer to restore Comments when I restore a Post.

The following will throw the exact same exception `InvalidArgumentException with message 'Illegale operator and value combination.'` :

```php
$post->comments()->withTrashed()->where('deleted_at', '>=', $post->deleted_at)->get()->each->restore();
```

The `where()` condition allows me to restore only comments softdeleted alongside the post's softdeletion (so that it does not also restore comments deleted by moderators prior to the whole post deletion).

Comment: Looks like you might encounter this [error](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3ec56b8810bc40016252977c69ba27057dcecf7d/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L763) is the respective `$value` is null. [The condition](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3ec56b8810bc40016252977c69ba27057dcecf7d/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L747) where the error may be thrown.

Comment: I identified the bug. The Observer triggers on ```restored()``` Post model event. So the ```$post->deleted_at``` attribute is ```null``` after first iteration (which explains why it updated only the first database row and then threw an exception since then it performs ```>=``` on null. I managed to quickfix changing ```restored()``` to ```restoring()``` but I'm not happy with it. I want to restore comments after the post is restored, not before.

Answer (score 0):

$post->comments()->onlyTrashed()->get()->each->restore();

Don't know if it helps but you can try this. Since restore can only work on trashed posts maybe that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Also I don't think you need withTrashed() when you are deleting. Because a trashed comment can't be trashed twice. I'm sure if your run this twice it will open a problem like restore is. just do

Comment: $post->comments()->get()->each->delete();

Answer (score 0):

```
        $post->comments()
            ->onlyTrashed()->where('deleted_at', '>=', $post->deleted_at)
            ->get()
            ->each->restore();
```

This actually works. The problem was because my Observer triggers at `restored`, which would cause `$post->deleted_at` to be `null` right after first iteration. Problem was fixed using `restoring()` model event instead of `restored()`.

This (above) answers my initial question.

I have not yet figured a way to keep using `restored` (I want comments to be restored after the post is restored), since `restored` makes `$post->deleted_at` become `null` thus non valid within my `where()` condition. I need to find a way to hold the original `$post->deleted_at` value, while using `restored()`. `getDirty()` and `getChanges()` did not help. I will accept my own answer in 3 days unless someone shares a way to also keep the `restored` event. I believe this is out of the scope of the initial question anyway?